# Electron app notorizing. Notorized electron app cannot be opened on other machines

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-notarize

Currently I'm working on notorizing electron app for Mac using electron-builder ("electron-builder": "^22.9.1") and electron-notorize ("electron-notorize": ^1.0.0) packages. Build successfully passes. Checking app signing and notorizing statuses with

```
pkgutil --check-signature /Path_to_App/My_App.app


   Package "XXXXXXX":
   Status: signed by a certificate trusted by macOS
   Certificate Chain:...
```

and

```
spctl -a -t exec -vvv /Path_to_App/My_App.app 

/Applications/XXXXXX.app: accepted
source=Notarized Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: XXXXXXXX
```

tells that app was signed and notarized.
But when I open it on another machine I get popup with a message that app cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
I've tried different options in build config and plist files, but still can't understand the cause of this issue.
My build config in package.json

```
"build": {
    "appId": "com.XXXX.XX",
    "productName": "XXXXXXX",
    "afterSign": "electron/notarize.js",
    "extends": null,
    "buildDependenciesFromSource": true,
    "files": [
      "build/**/*"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    },
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.productivity",
      "icon": "build/icon.icns",
      "hardenedRuntime": true,
      "gatekeeperAssess": false,
      "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mac.plist",
      "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mac.plist",
      "electronLanguages": [
        "en"
      ],
      "target": ["dmg"]
    },
    "dmg": {
      "sign": false
    },
```

And entitlements.mac.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <!-- https://github.com/electron/electron-notarize#prerequisites -->
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <!-- https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3940 -->
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>

    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
    <true/>

    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection</key>
    <true/>

    <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.automation.apple-events</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.audio-input </key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.camera</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.microphone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.bluetooth</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: removing the `com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation` entitlement will solve the warning issue

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by doing:

Inside package.json, add under "mac":

`"asarUnpack": "**/*.node"`

This will tell the builder to unpack those node native binaries so that the notarization can examine these libraries.

And in the entitlements file used for signing, REMOVE:

`<key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key> <true/>`

Then, it should work as expected.

Comment: That works for me. I had a similar issue after a USB library was added to my Angular Electron project.